# Error populating a QTableWidget in set item ¡

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have this code where Almacenador is a QStringList pupulated by this :

```
("250", "100", "9500", "400", "180", "100", "8400", "400", "110", "200", "10000", "400", "110", "230", "9000", "400");
```

---

```
int filas = Almacenador.size()/Properties;
int columnas = Properties;
qDebug() << filas;
qDebug() << columnas;
ui->Workspace->setRowCount(filas);
ui->Workspace->setColumnCount(columnas);
int h = 0;
for( int r = 0 ; r < ui->Workspace->rowCount(); ++r )
{
    for( int c = 0; c < ui->Workspace->columnCount(); ++c )
    {
        QString value = Almacenador[h];
        h++;
        qDebug() << r << c << value;
        ui->Workspace->setItem(r, c, new QTableWidgetItem(value));
        ui->Workspace->setItem(r,c,new QTableWidgetItem (value));
    }
}
```

I get the error in `ui->Workspace-SetItem(r,c,new QTableWidgetItem(value));`. But if i changed the value, i.e `QString value = "Empty";` The QTableWidget gets full.

Comment: What is the value of Properties?

Comment: Properties is declare  in this way: int Properties = 4;

Comment: I have tested the code you have placed and I have had no problems. But I have a curiosity, in the error says that you used `ui->Workspace-SetItem(..)` instead of `ui->Workspace->setItem(...)`

Comment: Could you show me how to store the data in `Almacenador`?

Comment: Well thats a problem of writing here but i still have the same error in that line. It crash after printing r, c and the value, i dont know if there is a  difference between this QString Example = "123" and QString Example = "Empty"

Comment: Have you included the necessary headers?

Comment: #include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QTableWidgetItem>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QVector>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>

Comment: Could you share your code via github or similar?

Comment: mmaybe Dropbox?

Comment: Of course, dropbox is fine.

Comment: Here is the app = https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ribi9wyevf3khy7/AADfm_dNlQTYmMsHGuNv9Y_0a?dl=0  with a file .csv , to see the problem you have to open the file, that file was saved from the program. The problem is at tabladatos.cpp line  169 - 190, sorry for the extra lines but i have been trying everything. Thanks.

Comment: Do you speak spanish?

Comment: Solve the problem, the code and the explanation is here: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/SoftwareHEN

Comment: Yes, thank you i will check it :)

Comment: Where are you from? My mail is e.yllanescucho@gmail.com, You must not write in Spanish here, delete your question since there is no information to solve.